# How do I add Crashlytics to AIDE?

Tags: android, crashlytics, aide-ide, crashlytics-android

I use AIDE while on the go. On Android Studio I added Crashlytics to my project but upon moving it over to AIDE,it doesn't seem to recognize  Crashlytics. Specifically, this line is specified as an unknown dependant according to compile error:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true}
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this or is AIDE incapable of supporting Crashlytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have the plugin preinstalled in Android Studio - https://fabric.io/downloads

Then in your `build.gradle`, add/update the following at the very top:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    // Fabric
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

If AIDE does not work properly, then please download the AAR library, then copy it in your `/libs` folder (say the name of the file is `fabric-2.5.2.aar`
Update `build.gradle` as follow:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    // Fabric
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

// .aar repositories
repositories {
  flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
}

dependencies {
  compile(name: 'fabric-2.5.2', ext: 'aar')
  ...
}
```

Comment: Works just fine in Android Studio, doesn't work at all in AIDE. Even placed the jar files from the zip in the libs folder, nada. My only guess is AIDE has no support for plug-ins such as this

Comment: This is an `AAR` library, not a JAR one. You need to copy/paste the `AAR` in your `/libs` folder and define the folder as a local repo. Will update the answer

Comment: where can I download the AAR? Edit found it nvm

Comment: https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/

Comment: Yeah found it. (Tho 2.5.2) wasn't there. Thanks for the help!